# Web service application published on IIS not making logs in its folder

Tags: web-services, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have a webservice application published on IIS 7.5.7600.16385.

Its path is:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\My.Apps.WebServices.MyHelloWorld
```

I have programmed this web service application in order to generate logs in some cases when some conditions are satisfied but I cannot see the logs are being created on its root folder:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\My.Apps.WebServices.MyHelloWorld
```

Its application pool is configured as classic mode with identity set to an account, let's say, MyMachine\Admin.

I do not know if it is necessary some kind of permissions to be set to the identity used by the application pool.

What can I do in order to my web service successfully creates the logs in its root folder?

Comment: "I have programmed this web service application in order to generate logs", so time to show some code.

Comment: Why are you writing logs into the web Root?  Normally you would use a separate folder as files in the webroot could be downloaded.

Comment: Ensure app pool identity user `MyMachine\Admin` has write permission on logs folder.

Comment: Finally the problem was in the way I was making the log.